# distributing 6 distinct objects into 2 sets of 4 boxes, no more than 2 identical objects per set

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

If anyone can help me with the formula and how to go about plotting a table of the combinations for the following, it will stop my brain from melting and I would be very grateful.

Each selection will consist of $8$ objects

The selection will be made from $6$ different colours $(A, B, C, D, E, F)$ (any $2$ colours will be duplicated)

I have $2$ boxes $(L, M)$, each with $4$ compartments $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ to receive $1$ object

The same colour may not be duplicated in the same box.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are we to regard two objects of color $A$ as identical so that switching them does not change the arrangement?  Assuming that is the case...then you have to have one each of the pairs in each of the boxes, so you are only asked to distribute the other $4$ objects.  That you ought to be able to do by hand, no?

Comment: Hi Lulu, Yes each of the pairs will be identical e.g. A may appear in each box and also F may appear in each box, leaving B, C, D & E to be distributed. I still need a little help with plotting this please

Comment: I don't understand.  If you objects are $\{A,A,B,B,C,D,E,F\}$ then your boxes must look like $(A,B,_,_)$, $(A,B,_,_)$ and you just have to put $\{C,D,E,F\}$ into the four slots.  There are, obviously, $\binom 42=6$ ways to do that.  Then, if you want, you can permute the contents of the two boxes, so multiply by $4!\times 4!$.  That's if the order inside the boxes matters.  What's the problem?